# Mover archivos anteriores a un mes PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Buenos días, 
Tengo una duda con un script de PowerShell.
Se ejecuta todos los días 1 de cada mes, y tiene que mover a otra ruta, todos los ficheros que se crearon anteriores a un mes. Es decir, si se ejecuta el 1 de Agosto tiene que mover todos los ficheros creados hasta el 1 de Julio, dejando sin tocar del 1 al 31 de julio.

Yo tengo esto:

```
 $lastmonth = (get-date).AddMonths(-1).ToUniversalTime()
```

esto me da el mismo día pero del mes anterior al que se ejecuta, con lo que si se ejecuta el día 1 me dará el día 1 del mes anterior.

He pensado en hacer un "IF" cumpliendo la condición de que se creasen antes (-le) del día 1 del mes anterior, pero actualmente estoy aprendiendo PowerShell y no estoy muy fino, agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda.

Hasta el momento llevo esto:

```
$lastmonth = (get-date).AddMonths(-1).ToUniversalTime()

Get-ChildItem E:\Backup |
    ? { $_.CreationTime -le $lastmonth  } |
    ForEach { Move-Item -path E:\Backup\* -destination F:\Backup_Process}
```

Pero me mueve todos los ficheros sin discriminar, he comprobado que hasta el *ForEach* me cumple la condición, mostrando los ficheros anteriores a un mes.
Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Vale... después de mucho probar he dado con la solución:

```
# Mover ficheros hasta un mes antes de su ejecución
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
$lastmonth = (get-date).AddMonths(-1).ToUniversalTime()

Get-ChildItem E:\Backup |

    ? { $_.CreationTime -le $lastmonth  } | 
        Move-Item -destination F:\Backup_Process
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Yo mismo estaba pisando la condición de la salida del comando que discriminaba por meses al intentar moverlo todo.
Aquí lo dejo por si le es útil a alguien.
Un saludo